# How is it possible to have a good EXPLAIN and a slow query?

Tags: mysql, performance

How is it possible to have a good plan in EXPLAIN like below and have a slow query. With few rows, using index, no filesort.

The query is running in 9s. The main table has around 500k rows.

When I had 250k rows in that table, the query was running in < 1s.

Suggestions plz?

[image: explain]

Query (1. fields commented can be enabled according user choice. 2. Without FORCE INDEX I got 14s. 3. SQL_NO_CACHE I use to prevent false results):

```
    SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
          p.property_id
        , lct.loc_city_name_pt
        , lc.loc_community_name_pt
        , lc.loc_community_image_num_default
        , lc.loc_community_gmap_longitude
        , lc.loc_community_gmap_latitude
    FROM property as p FORCE INDEX (ix_order_by_perf)
    INNER JOIN loc_community lc 
        ON lc.loc_community_id = p.property_loc_community_id
    INNER JOIN loc_city lct FORCE INDEX (loc_city_id)
        ON lct.loc_city_id = lc.loc_community_loc_city_id
    INNER JOIN property_attribute pa
        ON pa.property_attribute_property_id = p.property_id        
    WHERE p.property_published = 1
        AND (p.property_property_type_id = '1' AND p.property_property_type_sale_id = '1') 
        AND p.property_property_housing_id = '1' 
--      AND p.property_loc_community_id = '36'  
--      AND p.property_bedroom_id = '2'
--      AND p.property_price >= '50000' AND p.property_price <= '150000'
--      AND lct.loc_city_id = '1'
--      AND p.property_loc_subcommunity_id IN(7,8,12) 
    ORDER BY 
          p.property_featured DESC
        , p.property_ranking_date DESC
        , p.property_ranking_total DESC
    LIMIT 0, 15
```

Query Profile

[image: query profile]

The resultset always outputs 15 rows. But the table property and property_attribute has around 500k rows.

Thanks all,

Armando Miani

Comment: Show the query, schema, and SHOW PROFILE result please. Also, how many rows are in the result set?

Comment: No order. No slow. supressing ORDER BY gets in 0,0000...2s. =/ I've already have an index embracing all fields in ORDER BY.

Comment: Your query is NOT using an index to satisfy the WHERE clause. The EXPLAIN shows this (the index is not displayed in 'possible_keys' column). Show your full schema, with indexes, if you need help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a moment when your query will be optimized around a model which might not be anymore valid for a given need.

A plan could be great but, even if the filters you are using in the where clause respect indexes definitions, it doesn't mean the parser doesn't parse may rows.

What you have to analize is how determinating are your indexes. For instance, if there's an index on "name, family name" in a "person" table, the performances are going to be poor if everybody has the same name and family name. The index is a real trap pulling down performances when it doesn't manage to be enough describing a certain segment of your datasets.

Comment: Hmmmm maybe you've got the problem! I made some optimizations and got 0,0002s in this query in my production database (250k). Then I'd like to stress this query and see how far we could go. Duplicated all rows in property and property_attribute table.

Comment: The production database has much more heterogeneus data.

Comment: add some random to your duplicate values, such as timestamp() or something like this.

This is a very nasty yet usually undercovered problem in sql tunning

Answer (score 2):

This really seems to be an odditity in EXPLAIN in this case. This doesn't occur on MySQL 4.x, but it does on MySQL 5.x.

What MySQL is really showing you is that MySQL is trying to use the forced index `ix_order_by_perf` for sorting the rows, and it's showing you 15 rows because you have LIMIT 15.

However, the WHERE clause is still scanning all 500K rows since it can't utilize an index for the criteria in your WHERE clause. If it were able to use the index for finding the required rows, you would see the forced index listed in the 'possible_keys' field.

You can prove this by keeping the `FORCE INDEX` clause and removing the `ORDER BY` clause. You'll see that MySQL now won't use any indexes, even the one you're forcing (because the index doesn't work for this purpose).

Try adding property_property_type_id, property_property_type_sale_id, property_property_housing_id, and any other columns that you refer to in your WHERE clause to the beginning of the index.

Comment: Hmmm I don't think so. The possible_keys is supressed when I use FORCE INDEX

Comment: FORCE INDEX does not prevent other keys from being used, it just makes it unlikely. If the optimizer thinks that Index is useless, it's going to use something else.

Comment: yeap. But always when I use FORCE INDEX the column possible_keys is supressed from EXPLAIN

Comment: @armandomiani, try changing your WHERE clause to utilize only the first column in the forced index, and you'll see that it fills in 'possible_keys' with the forced index. I've reproduced your issue completely.

Comment: @armandomiani, I clarified my answer to indicate that you should add the columns in the WHERE clause to the 'beginning' of the index.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output of your explain the query, here are my initial thoughts:

This portion of your query (rewritten to excluded the unneeded parentheses):

```
    p.property_published = 1
    AND p.property_property_type_id = '1' 
    AND p.property_property_type_sale_id = '1'
    AND p.property_property_housing_id = '1'
```

Put conditions so many conditions on the `property` table that it's unlikely any index you have can be used. Unless you have a single index that has all four of those attributes in it, you're forcing a full table scan on the query just to find the rows that meet those conditions (though, it's possible if you have an index on one of the attributes it could use that).

First, I'd add the following index (have not checked this for syntax errors):

```
CREATE INDEX property_published_type_sale_housing_idx  
ON property (property_published, 
             property_property_type_id, 
             property_property_type_sale_id, 
             property_property_housing_id );
```

Then I'd re-run your `EXPLAIN` to see if you hit the index now. (Take off the `FORCE INDEX` on that part of the query).

Also, even given this issue, it's possible the slow down may be *memory* related. That is, you may have enough memory to process the table with a smaller number of rows, but it may be that when the table gets larger MySQL can't process the entire query in memory and is forced to start using disk to get the entire query handled. This would explain why there's a sudden drop off in performance.

If that's the case, then two things might help:

1. Adding more memory (and tune the mysql config file to take advantage of it) so that the number of rows that can br processed at once is larger. This is at best a temporary solution.
2. Tune the indexes (like I'm saying above) so that the number of rows that mysql needs to process is lower. If it can be more precise in picking the rows it selects for processing.

Comment: Did you change the query? If not, the explain is in question

Comment: I didn't change the query. Sorry I didn't see the way it was embedded in the graphic. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That's possible. As part of stressing test. I'm doing it in a sux ubuntu 256mb ram

Comment: Good. Temporary adding more memory got faster. I was with 256mb ram. Increased to 1gb and got 1s. Our production server runs with 64gb. I won't worry for a while with it.

Comment: I liked your solution with the indexes. But look the query again. There are some commented fields. These fields are enabled/disabled according user choices on screen. How can I set a index that embrace all possibilities. One index embrancing all possible where columns or many indexes with the most common choices?

Comment: I don't believe you need *all* the attributes in the index, just a choice few. MySQL can sort in memory the rows it pulls back based on the other attributes -- the main thing is to get it pulling back a relatively small number of rows based on the first index. Main thing is get it to hit the index at all.

Comment: I'm glad  I was able to help. If you felt this contributed to your finding a solution, I'd appreciate you accepting the answer. Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

except a good plan you need to have enough resources to run query.

check buffers size and another critical parameters in your config.

And your query is?

Comment: Can I put the query here? Once I've put things about my job and received penalties like: Too localized

Comment: @armandomiani, you won't receive that with optimization questions. Put it in the question please.